# SQLのDDLを実行時、"user does not exist" エラーになる

Tags: sql

タイトル通り、Oracle SQL Developer でDDLを実行するとき
以下のようなエラーが表示された場合はどのように対応したらいいですか。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
ORA-01435: ユーザーが存在しません。
01435. 00000 -  "user does not exist"
```

**実行したSQL**

```
---------------------------
--新規 FUNCTION
--SHIFT
---------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SICSPC"."SHIFT" 
( 
    P_DATE IN DATE
 )
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  str_rtn VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) <  8 THEN 'N'
         WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) < 20 THEN 'D'
         ELSE 'N'
     END
    INTO str_rtn
    FROM DUAL;
  RETURN str_rtn;
END SHIFT;
/
```

Comment: DDLを実行するときのユーザ(スキーマ)は何ですか？　SICSPCでしょうか？別のユーザ(スキーマ)でしょうか。別であれば、単純にSICSPCが存在しないか、DDLを実行するときのユーザにシステム権限が付与されていない気がします。

Comment: 別のユーザーに変更したらできました。

Comment: user25636 さんは「表領域の作成でエラー」の質問をされた方ですね、そのときのcubickさんのコメントを転記します。「スタック・オーバーフローでは 自己回答 も歓迎しています。コメント欄はあくまでメモ書きという位置付けなので、「回答」の形で投稿してもらうと同じような問題で困ったユーザーがいた際に情報が見つけやすくなります。」私も自己回答することがありますが、自分のためでもあります。

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SICSPC"."SHIFT"` の "SICSPC" がユーザー名なので、
存在するユーザー名に変更する。

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SICSPC"."SHIFT" 
( 
    P_DATE IN DATE
 )
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
  str_rtn VARCHAR2(2);
BEGIN
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) <  8 THEN 'N'
         WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(P_DATE AS TIMESTAMP)) < 20 THEN 'D'
         ELSE 'N'
     END
    INTO str_rtn
    FROM DUAL;
  RETURN str_rtn;
END SHIFT;
/
```